# Infinite Sequence based on Simple Rule

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, number-sequence, no-computers

Using one simple rule, an Infinite Sequence has been developed.

First 30 terms are given. Can you continue the sequence for at least next Ten Terms?

Series continues from top left to bottom right.

$3, 31, 41, 59, 53, 89, 97, 79, 23, 43,$

$83, 79, 2, 41, 19, 97, 71, 37, 5, 97$

$59, 23, 7, 89, 3, 53, 11, 17 ,67, 79$

$\text{Next 10}$?

Comment: please change it to **30** terms

Comment: Happy to see something different, this is a good start.

Comment: Can you confirm that 51 is really correct and not a typo for, say, 53 or 61?

Comment: Can you confirm if infinite sequence means an infinite sequence that does not repeat?

Comment: @tom..if you mean, cyclic..it is not..Sequence is not finite..of course numbers can repeat as you can see in the numbers given.

Comment: Working on the rest,,double checking to make sure that there are no errors..

Comment: At first I thought they were all odd. But 2 was even. Then I thought they were all primes. But after a few minutes, I just noticed that 51=3*17.

Comment: After double checking my notebook and the posted..as per Gareth and alto..51 shouldn’t be there..thx for pointing out..rest I double checked..looks ok..I will edit as per am also.

Comment: One more edit was made..adding 11 as 27th term..now full 30 terms are given..thx for catching the mistakes and timely pointing out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The next terms are:

> 13, 23, 47, 5, 23, 31, 17, 53, 59, 11

Because

> These are the primes found in pairs of digits of $\pi$.
>
> ```
> 31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
> || | |   |  |||  |      |  |  |  |   ||||      |   |    |     | | |            |      |    |   ||  ||
> 3|41 |  53 89|| 23     43  | 79 02  41|71     37  05   97    59 |07           89     03   53  11| 67|
> 31  59      97|           83         19|                       23                              17  79
>              79                       97
> ```

Comment: @florian..excellent!!

Comment: Thanks!  It's the 3 numbers 31,41,59 that gave it away.  After that it was a piece of pie.

Comment: I could have made it tougher ...but I want to make it only slightly complex and a series not to be found in oeis...opens up for so many avenues of further research into this fascinating field

Comment: It would be nice to examine the prime gaps and frequency of various primes generated via this method through computer calculations.

Comment: The digits of pi being practically random, the frequency of each prime should be constant at 1 occurrence everu 100 digits.